# Android SwipeRefreshLayout stops on swipe and not animating

Tags: android, android-layout, swiperefreshlayout

I'm currently implementing a swiperefreshlayout on my project when I encountered a problem wherein the swiperefresh icon stops and is not animating also not refreshing at all. it just stays there and nothing happens. I guess this is a problem with the layout so here's my current layout XML:

main activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.myapp.customviews.CustomViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/colors"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tabs"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:layout_gravity="right|top" />

    <include android:id="@+id/toolbar" layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_gravity="right|top" />


</FrameLayout>
```

So my main activity consist of a frame layout with a custom view pager which can just toggle paging enable and disable. A toolbar and a tabstrip. toolbar will hide on scroll of the recyclerview which uses this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        android:id="@+id/swipe_home">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:clipToPadding="false"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

now this layout is being used in a fragment which is added to the view pager of the main activity. I just set a padding for my recyclerview to make sure that the item content shown properly but when I pull to refresh it the rounded refresh icon swiperefreshlayout just stops and there goes the problem. I've worked on swiperefresh layout before but this is the first time I've encountered this problem. Hope someone can point out where the problem is.

UPDATE:

I tried to change the content of swipe to refresh from RecyclerView into ScrollView and the pull to refresh works fine! But scroll view is not what I need so I need to push on the RecyclerView which is still not working and freezes. I think there is something wrong with the RecyclerView and SwipeRefreshLayout implementation.

Comment: Can you show your java code for SwipeRefreshLayout?

Comment: I currently didn't implement code yet on the SwipeRefreshLayout as for the recyclerview I just use a test data to add item for list and nothing else. it works on other scrollable view but not on recyclerview. Weird thing is that I tried this before and it works fine but now I just freezes. I'll check on my libraries today there might be some conflict

Comment: Check this [link](http://androhub.com/android-swiperefresh-layout/) for swiperefresh layout example.

Comment: The layout I'm using is already good. The problem is with the support libraries so I just updated it and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there is a problem with the support library I'm using after updating my all support library from 22.2.0 to 23.1.1 then changed the compileSdkVersion to 23 and updated the gradle to 1.3.0 to support `useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'` the problem is now fixed and swipe refresh works as expected.